# Disable the yellow warning messages in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Disable or enable the yellow warning messages in react-native, whenever running the simulator you will get warning messages so it will waste of time so you can add this command to save time.

Answer (score 0):

add this below command in your root project like index.js

console.disableYellowBox = true;